# How to improve efficiency of parsing thousands of lines in hundreds of files

Tags: python, performance

I have a script written, but it is prohibitively slow. I'm wondering if someone could suggest how to speed it up. The part of the script that I think is too slow is like this:

1. I have a list of 1,000 human gene names (each gene name is a number), read into a list called "ListOfHumanGenes"; for example, the start of the list looks like this:

   `[2314,2395,10672,8683,5075]`
2. I have 100 files like this, all with the extension ".HumanHomologs":

   ```
   HumanGene   OriginalGene    Intercept    age    pval 
   2314       14248            5.3e-15      0.99   3.5e-33 
   2395       14297            15.76       -0.05   0.59 
   10672      14674            7.25         0.19   0.58 
   8683       108014           21.63       -1.74   0.43 
   5075       18503            -6.34        1.58   0.19
   ```
3. The algorithm of this section of the script is to say (in english, not code):

> ```
> for each gene in ListOfHumanGenes:
>     open each of the 100 files labelled ".HumanHomologs"
>       if the gene name is present:
>            NumberOfTrials +=1
>            if the p-val is <0.05: 
>                  if the "Age" column < 0:
>                        UnderexpressedSuccess +=1
>                  elif "Age" column > 0:
>                        OverexpressedSuccess +=1
> print each_gene + "\t" + NumberOfTrials + "\t" UnderexpressedSuccess
> print each_gene + "\t" + NumberOfTrials + "\t" OverexpressedSuccess
> ```

The code for this section is:

```
for each_item in ListOfHumanGenes:
    OverexpressedSuccess = 0
    UnderexpressedSuccess = 0
    NumberOfTrials = 0
    for each_file in glob.glob("*.HumanHomologs"):
        open_each_file = open(each_file).readlines()[1:]
        for line in open_each_file:
            line = line.strip().split()
            if each_item == line[0]:
                NumberOfTrials +=1    #i.e if the gene is in the file, NumberOfTrials +=1. Not every gene is guaranteed to be in every file
                if line[-1] != "NA":
                    if float(line[-1]) < float(0.05):
                        if float(line[-2]) < float(0):
                            UnderexpressedSuccess +=1
                        elif float(line[-2]) > float(0):
                            OverexpressedSuccess +=1

    underexpr_output_file.write(each_item + "\t" + str(UnderexpressedSuccess) + "\t" + str(NumberOfTrials) + "\t" + str(UnderProbability) +"\n") #Note: the "Underprobabilty" float is obtained earlier in the script
    overexpr_output_file.write(each_item + "\t" + str(OverexpressedSuccess) + "\t" + str(NumberOfTrials) + "\t" + str(OverProbability) +"\n") #Note: the "Overprobability" float is obtained earlier in the script
overexpr_output_file.close()
underexpr_output_file.close()
```

This produces two output files (one for over and one for under-expressed) that looks like this; the columns are GeneName, #Overexpressed/#Underexpressed, #NumberTrials, and then the last column can be ignored:

```
2314    8   100 0.100381689982
2395    14  90  0.100381689982
10672   10  90  0.100381689982
8683    8   98  0.100381689982
5075    5   88  0.100381689982
```

Each of the ".HumanHomologs" files has >8,000 lines in it, and the list of genes is ~20,000 genes long. So I understand this is slow because for each of the 20,000 genes, it's opening 100 files and finding the gene among > 8,000 genes per file. I was wondering if anyone could suggest edits I could make to make this script quicker/more efficient?

Comment: What about the `csv` module or `pandas`? Also switch round your `ListOfHumanGenes` and file reading loops. Put the file reading loop as the outer loop, thus meaning you only open each file once. Opening each file once per gene will kill performance.

Answer (score 1):

your algorithm will open all these 100 files 1000times. The optimization that comes to mind immediately is iterate through the files as the most outer loop, which will make sure each file will be only opened once. Then check each gene presence and record any other records you want.

Also, pandas module will be very handy in handling this kinda csv files. check it out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help; the insight to swap the loops around was invaluable.
The improved and far, far more efficient script is as follows: (One note: Instead of having a ListOfHumanGenes (as described above), I now have a DictOfHumanGenes, where each key is the human gene, and the values are a list of (1) NumberOfTrials, (2) UnderexpressedSuccess and (3) OverexpressedSuccess; this also sped up other parts of my code):

```
for each_file in glob.glob("*.HumanHomologs"):
    open_each_file = open(each_file).readlines()[1:]
    for line in open_each_file:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if line[0] in DictOfHumanGenes: 
            DictOfHumanGenes[line[0]][0] +=1  #This is the Number of trials
            if line[-1] != "NA":
                if float(line[-1]) < float(0.05):
                    if float(line[-2]) < float(0):
                        DictOfHumanGenes[line[0]][1] +=1  #This is the UnexpressedSuccess
                    elif float(line[-2]) > float(0):
                        DictOfHumanGenes[line[0]][2] +=1  #This is the OverexpressedSuccess
```

I am now looking into pandas to see how to incorporate that, if I can make the code even more efficient with pandas I'll post the answer here.